# xcode - asset catalog - image type - same scale - different resolutions

Tags: ios, asset-catalog

I have an iOS application which is developed years ago and sets backgrounds of many controls using images.xcassets catalog. The images are set using contents.json in which targets are iPhone, iPad using 'idiom' key. Further specifications include 'scale' & 'filename'. Seems that this app worked fine until iOS 8.

As of today there are many high screen resolution devices of iPhone, iPad. So, I need to add further more images targeting these high screen resolution devices.

I don't know how it is handled earlier, but now there are different screen resolutions in the same scale factor. For e.g., iPad Pro 12.9" & iPad Pro 11" have '2x' as scale factor but has different resolutions '2048x2732' & '1668x2388' respectively. Now if I create an image targeting highest resolution 2048x2732, the image is not getting centered for resolution 1668x2388.

1. Is there any particular key in contents.json that can differentiate screen resolutions/sizes for the same scale factor?
2. When I search for Apple's documentation for asset catalog it is found in this [documentation archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/ImageSetType.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015170-CH25-SW1). Does that mean we shouldn't use asset catalog for images any more? Are there any latest standards for setting background images?

Comment: Are you editing Contents.json and the folder content directly? If so, why don’t you edit the assets in Xcode where you can add easily images for any device and resolution?

Comment: I recommend you remove launch images in images.xcassets and setup it with LaunchScreen. It save your space.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Though I do it using assets in Xcode, is there a possibility that I can set the same image for iPhone X & iPhone XS Max which are of same scale 3x but different resolutions & aspect ratios? When I set an image with a logo at center for resolution (1242x2688) of iPhone XS Max, the logo is not centered properly for iPhone X. Even if I use "UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext" for background stretching the image on iPhone X looks compressed horizontally.

Comment: @Aisner I think LaunchScreen is used only during loading of app. Can we use it throughout all the scenes in the app?

Comment: @DSuryaPraveen i think you can't use LaunchScreen like UIViewController, because LaunchScreen have specific restrictions, for example - don't have any animation, dynamic, etc. You can make a UIView which looks like LaunchScreen.

Comment: You have to use the correct image size in order to drag it into the Xcode asset placeholders. If it does not fit, you will get an error what is wrong. This means that you really have to prepare images of correct size for all devices and resolutions. In many cases, i.e. if only a logo has to be centered, this is overkill, but in general it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options you can follow for setting background images for different devices.

1-) Setting `UIImageView` content mode to `.aspectFill`. By settings this property, your image will be croped for different aspect ratios but original aspect ratio will be protected. I recommend this option If you use repetitive images for background.

2-) Setting two different asset file for different aspect ratio and resolution. If you follow this option, in code, you need to check for the device and set the proper image asset.

```
let image: UIImage!
if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
    case 1920, 2208:
        print("iPhone 6+/6S+/7+/8+")
        image = UIImage(named:"StandartBackground.png")
    case 2436:
        print("iPhone X, XS")
        image = UIImage(named:"XBackground.png")
    case 2688:
        print("iPhone XS Max")
        image = UIImage(named:"XSBackground.png")
    }
}
```

**Advice:** Common and proper way is first option but there will be cases which won't suite it. Therefore, try to avoid second option but If have no other option. Put every different **aspect ratio** to different asset file.

Comment: This is the type of answer I'm looking for. I heard UIImageView is used for displaying photos only. Can this be used for background images also? Can you provide any example?

Comment: Option "asset catalog" is the existing method currently implemented in our project. Regarding adding more images for supporting further resolutions, I'm afraid about app size may increase on adding more and more images.

Comment: How do you add background images now?

Comment: I am adding images using "asset catalog"